# C menu system - switch not triggering

Tags: c

I've been looking at this issue for a while now and I know it's super basic but can't for the life of me work out where it's going wrong.

Basic menu system in C, takes in an integer and returns the appropriate result:

The menu displays fine, it takes the input fine but it doesn't seem to trigger the switch ie. if I hit option 1, it doesn't display the message.

```
int main(void) {

    #define LSIZE 5
    int selection[LSIZE];
    do {
        printf("\n Welcome to Menu");
        printf("1) option 1\n");
        printf("2) option 2\n");
        printf("3) QUIT \n");

        while (fgets(selection, LSIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
             puts(selection);
        }

         if(scanf("%i", &selection) != 1) {
                printf("\nInvalid input\n");
                return EXIT;
            } else {
                switch(*selection) {
                    case '1':
                        printf("Selected option 1\n");
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        printf("Selected option 2\n");
                        break;
                    default:
                        printf("invalid option, try again \n");
                 }
             }
          } while (*selection != '3');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: `'1'` should be `1`, etc.

Comment: Also, why is `selection` an array?

Comment: `scanf("%i", &selection)` is very wrong. You attempt to wrinte the resulting `int` value into a the string array. You should create an `int` variable to store the result.

Comment: `*selection` seems wrong too... though I might be misreading that one

Comment: You `fgets` loop will not end until there's an error reading, or the user pressed the end-of-file key sequence. In either case the stream `stdin` will be put in such a state that it can't be used again.

Comment: Lastly, the `exit` function expects an argument (a small non-negative integer). Just remove that line. And in the future listen to your compiler, which should have shouted warnings at you. Treat those warnings as errors that must be fixed. And build with extra verbose warnings.

Comment: `puts(selection)` seems odd as well.

Comment: You could use an int variable `int select` and change the if statement to `if(sscanf(selection, "%i", &select) == 1)`, and then use the variable `select` in the switch statement (and change the matching case labels to integer numbers instead of characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int selection[LSIZE];
...
while (fgets(selection, LSIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
    puts(selection);
}
...
if(scanf("%i", &selection) != 1) {
```

This is very confused.  You've declared `selection` as an array of `int`, but you're reading a string into it as though it were an array of `char`, *and then* you're trying to read a single decimal integer into it, but you're passing the address of the *array*, not a single `int` element.

Let's simplify it a bit and only worry about reading the menu option.  We'll read it as an `int`, so we'd change our code as follows:

```
int selection;

do 
{
  // print menu options

  if ( scanf( "%d", &selection ) != 1 )
    // handle bad input
  else
  {
    switch( selection )
    {
      case 1 : // not '1'
        // handle option 1
        break;

      case 2: 
        // handle option 2
        break;

      default:
        break;
  }
} while ( selection != 3 );
```

etc.  This should get you past your initial hurdles.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
int main(void) {
    int selection;
    do {
        printf("\n Welcome to Menu");
        printf("1) option 1\n");
        printf("2) option 2\n");
        printf("3) QUIT \n");

         if(scanf("%d", &selection) != 1) {
                printf("\nInvalid input\n");
                return EXIT;
            } else {
                switch(selection) {
                    case 1:
                        printf("Selected option 1\n");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        printf("Selected option 2\n");
                        break;
                    default:
                        printf("invalid option, try again \n");
                 }
             }
          } while (*selection != '3');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: The case labels are still wrong, they should be `case 1` and `case 2` instead of `case '1'` and `case '2'`.

Comment: Also, replace the line `exit();` for `return 0;`. Using `exit()` without argument is wrong, and the proper way to end the `main` function is to return an integer number (in this case returns zero `0` to indicate that the program has reached its end correctly).